# Bitbucket/Forge file not updating

Tags: bitbucket, digital-ocean, forge

OK, this has me totally bamboozled.

I have a repo on Bitbucket that is deployed via Forge to a Digital Ocean server. (I actually have several sites on the Forge/DO server that all work fine).

When I look at the deployment log, I can see that the file is being updated correctly with no errors.

However, when I look at the site via a browser, the file has not been updated (have tried clearing browser cache and different browsers)!!

I know something silly is happening, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.

I have tried re-naming and completely deleting the file in question (it is a css file) but it always remains on the DO server even when I can see it is being renamed/removed on the deployment log.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going on?

I have even uninstalled/re-installed the repo.

I guess the next step would be to completely remove and then re-add the site in forge, but this seems ridiculous..?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the end I updated the link ref in my html head to another location and then added the file to the git repo under a different name.

It now works!

I guess it must have been some cache related issue, but still none the wiser!